# El Capitan unable to boot

Tags: macos, permission, root

I am using a Mac Book Pro with El Capitan installed. Yesterterday I was trying to change a file permission and I made a very big mistake.

This is the command I issued

`sudo chmod -R 777 /`

After issuing the command the system began to give many system errors. I restarted my laptop and now it keeps stack at the apple logo with the progress bar.

I have been able to go to the single user mode, buh I dnt know how to get the laptop to boot normally.

Anybody with an idea on this can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Boot to recovery HD and just reinstall the OS.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

This is done by Holding the <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd> keys down while turning on the Mac. You will then be given the option for reinstalling Mac OS. This **will not** delete any of your files, merely replace just the damaged Mac OS files.

All permissions will be fixed on the system side - no apps get deleted, no user accounts or date is deleted.

Worst case, you'll need to set up a new admin user on the machine once it's reinstalled (boot to single user move and delete /var/db/.AppleSetupDone) to finish changing permissions on your user folder.

You could also boot to internet recovery if normal recovery fails.

Comment: pls what do u mean by reinstall the OS? I am asking because I know that reinstalling the OS again will delete everything from my machine

Comment: I have made some edits on the answer that should clarify your questions.

Comment: I want to kindly confirm this so I dnt make mistake. I currently dnt have a copy of the OS. And when I go to the utility, I see `Reinstall a copy of OS`. Should I still continue following the process? At what point shld I stop the process? Thanks

Comment: @SteveChambers any knowledge whatsoever?

Comment: The OS is downloaded from Apple's servers, so you need an active network connection. Also you'll get the OS that came with the computer, so it may be an earlier version, which you can then upgrade if you like. Just reinstall the OS and let it fully complete.

Comment: @SteveChambers Actually, by default - Recovery HD is a local bootable image. You can't mess it up as it's not mounted on the / filesystem. You don't need internet recovery unless you mess up the both the normal OS and the recovery OS (or you mess up EFI / the entire partition map). It's not wrong to use internet recovery, just not quick or the easiest first step.

Comment: bmike, thx, I completely spaced out on that...

Comment: @bmike please do u have any steps to using the local recovery hd method to do the recovery

Comment: @George see my edit. Also Steve Chambers is correct. You need to download the installer as recovery is the tool to do the download if you haven't already created a bootable installer.

Comment: I have followed the process buh after logging with my apple ID, after some few seconds it tells me the the item is temporarily unavailable.